# Can you find a formula for the nth term of this particular sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recurrence-relations

While I was solving a question, I had to find out the values in specific cases. I found the individual values as: 0,0,1,6,35 for n = 1,2,3,4,5 respectively. Is there anyway to represent this as a function f(n)   $\forall$ n $\in \mathbb{Z}$ that uses (n!)

Comment: There are infinitely many functions satisfying these conditions.

Comment: Thanks for reminding @N.S.

Comment: "*While I was solving a specific questions...*"  The question is unanswerable in its current form, but might be answerable if you were to include the context of what question it was that you think this sequence arose from.

Comment: The question is completely different from what I asked for. It only asked for the value at various values of n. However, I wanted to search for a formula for general n. This thing has nothing to do with the question. This is not even the answer they are looking for. That is why I did not add it @JMoravitz

Comment: Context is important...  Without context we **cannot** know what the next number in the sequence is and thus cannot know what the general expression is.  We *can* come up with infinitely many different functions, each of whom involve factorials in some fashion whose first few terms match the first few terms of what you have given us so far to work with.  *If you were to share the specific original question* then from the details of the specific question we might be able to give the specific general form that generates that *specific* sequence.

Comment: If you want any help with this... you **must** share the original question... whether you think it is relevant or not, it very much is.  Whether the original question asked you to find the general form or not... if you want the general form to the answers to the original question... we **have to** know what that original question was.

Comment: If you insist on not sharing the original question, the only help we could possibly offer beyond telling you how bad the question you ask is... is to point you to www.oeis.org and [push the search button for you](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C0%2C1%2C6%2C35&language=english&go=Search) and suggest the various *possibly very many* sequences which contain or start with your proposed beginning of a sequence... many of which will be irrelevant, maybe one or a few might be relevant, but also very possibly the real sequence you are *actually* looking for might not even be on the list.

Comment: Some answers from [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C6%2C35&language=french&go=Chercher). For example [A081051 Unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://oeis.org/A081051).

Comment: To elaborate on Raymond's comment, he is suggesting the sequence $\begin{bmatrix}n\\3\end{bmatrix}$ where this is notation for the unsigned [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).  Stirling numbers of the first kind generally take *two* arguments, a top and a bottom.  Here, the proposed sequence was the one where the bottom was kept constant and equal to $3$.  Whether this has anything to do with your original problem or not though remains unknown until you clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, out of many ways, to represent your function is
$$
f(n)=(n-1)!- (-\frac{1}{3}n^4 + \frac{19}{6}n^3 - \frac{32}{3}n^2+ \frac{89}{6}n - 6).
$$
So $f(1)=0!-1=0$, $f(2)=0$, $f(3)=1$, $f(4)=6$ and $f(5)=13$.

Furthermore $f(6)=169$.

Of course, we cannot know what you could do with an arbitrary formula.